# How to show 3 columns on PC but only one on mobile>?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to have a big row containing all the stuff on my page and have it all centered so it fits one big column on the middle and have another two columns on the left/right (like in the image). Background color is for me to see their sizes.

[image]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:gray;">s</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1" style="background-color:gray;">s</div>
  <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:gray;">s</div>
</div>
```

What should I do so I can see all 3 columns on desktop but only see the middle one on mobile?

Comment: Would you be opposed to using css media queries?

Comment: It seems to me that you are missing the '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">' on your html. That code should do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to break at different points, you can use the different grid options (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options) classes. I've updated my code below to use native Bootstrap widths. I know you said you're looking for ~950 px breakpoint, so your options are 1. recompiling Bootstrap yourself with custom widths, or 2. using the built-in `lg` classes that work with >= 992px widths. For ease of implementation, I updated the classes below using the `lg` classes.

With Bootstrap 4 you can use the `.d-none` and `.col-lg-` utility classes (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/) to achieve this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="d-none d-lg-block col-lg-1">
        show 1 column on >= 992px, hide < 991px
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-lg-10">
        show on >= 992px full, < 991px 10 columns
    </div>

    <div class="d-none d-lg-block col-lg-1">
        show 1 column on >= 992px, hide < 991px
    </div>
</div>
```

Depending on your content in the middle column, you can use various other grid classes (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#setting-one-column-width) to adjust the width of any of the columns (if, for instance, `col-sm-1` is too small for the left/right columns).

Example at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WLyGpW

Comment: This is what I am trying to say.

https://jsfiddle.net/s2by86ag/

If the device is so small that the 3 columns stack, I need the two gray columns to disappear. (They don't include any data at all so I can hide them)

Comment: Ah, then instead of `d-none d-sm-block col-sm-1` on the first and third columns (which hides the column completely on mobile), you can just use `col-sm-1` which will make it full-width on mobile, and 1 column wide everywhere else. I've updated the codepen and my answer to reflect this. `col-12` is no longer necessary because it's the default width.

Comment: It was actually what I was looking for the first time, where the two cols would disappear. How can it be changed so the 2 laterla cols  dissapears as soon as I minimize the browser? So they are more 'sensitive' let's say

Comment: @VladutMaican code has been updated with an explanation at the top